# Some more examples of atomic formulas

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Fix a first order language $\mathscr{L}$. Let $t_1,t_2$ denote any two $\mathscr{L}$-terms, then one defines an atomic formula as,

$(1)$  $t_1=t_2$ is an atomic formula.

$(2)$ If $R$ is an $n$-ary relation symbol and $t_1,t_2....t_n$ are terms then $R(t_1,t_2..,t_n)$ is also an atomic formula.

I know one example of this i.e $F(x)=y$ (If we assume that $x,y$ as terms and $F$ be some unary function).
I was wondering if there exists some other examples for it.

Comment: Two more examples: $F(F(x))=y$ and $F(F(x))=F(y)$

Comment: @Primo Petri, yaa I even saw them a while ago as I was trying for examples. But I want something not constituting of a function symbol.

Comment: So I think it's possible. Let $\mathscr{M}$ be a $\mathscr{L}$ structure. $\mathscr{M}=\{A,+,-,·,0,1\}$ Its entirely possible in this structure that, $+(x,0)=x$ is an atomic formula. Where $x$ is a term.Am i correct?

Comment: Atomic formulas don't exist "in structures". They are defined based on *languages*. In the language $\{+,-,\cdot,0,1\}$, you are correct that $+(x,0) = x$ is an atomic formula (here $x$ is a variable). Another example is $+(x,1) = x$. We would more commonly write these formulas as $x+0 =x $ and $x+1 =x$.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman, Ok I see that. Now I doubt why is $+(x,1)=x$?

Comment: I agree that both $+(x,1)$ and $x$ are terms but in what sense does it mean that $x+1=x$??

Comment: $+(x,1)=x$ is a syntactically correct formula whose universal closure happens to be false (in structures like $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q$, etc. with the usual interpretation).

Comment: Note that also $+(0,0)=0$ is a well formed formula (i.e. variables do not necessarily occur).

Comment: @Rahul You're thinking about whether the formula $x+1 = x$ is true or false. This is jumping the gun. The point is to define what a formula *is*. Only after we have understood that $x+1 = x$ is a formula can we ask whether it is true or false. And it will be true in some structures and false in others.